# vuepress additionalPages added to sidebar

Tags: javascript, vuepress

I'm trying to create an AdditionalPage and add it inside the navbar.

I cannot find out how to make it happen:

This is my plugin:

```js
async additionalPages() {
     ...
    errorsPages.push({
      path: '/errors',
      content: '## Errors',
      frontmatter: {
        sidebar: true,
      },
    })
    return errorsPages
```

When I only do this, of course no `sidebar` are present. This is because I did not add my `/errors` page inside the navbar.

When I try to add it to
config.js in the `sidebar` option:

```js
 'sidebar': {
    '/references/': [
        {
          title: ' API References',
          path: '/references/',
          collapsable: false,
          children: [
            '/references/indexes',
            '/references/keys',
            {
              title: 'Errors',
              path: '/errors/',
              collapsable: false,
            },
         ]
      } 
   ]
}
```

Then the build failes.

Any idea how to add my additionalpages inside my sidebar ?

Answer (score 0):

For add groups in sidebar, try this code:

```js
sidebar: {
  '/guide/': [
    {
      title: 'Group Guide',
      children: ['', 'introduction-guide', 'details-guide'],
    },
  ],
  '/api/': [
    {
      title: 'Group API',
      children: ['', 'introduction-api', 'details-api'],
    },
  ],
},
```

The `introduction-guide` and `details-guide` are files presents in `guide` directory.

The `introduction-api` and `details-api` are files presents in `api` directory.

For more details: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#sidebar-groups